# Using For loop on nested list

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm using a nested list to hold data in a Cartesian coordinate type system.

The data is a list of categories which could be 0,1,2,3,4,5,255 (just 7 categories).

The data is held in a list formatted thus:

```
stack = [[0,1,0,0],
         [2,1,0,0],
         [1,1,1,3]]
```

Each list represents a row and each element of a row represents a data point.

I'm keen to hang on to this format because I am using it to generate images and thus far it has been extremely easy to use.

However, I have run into problems running the following code:

```
for j in range(len(stack)):
    stack[j].append(255)
    stack[j].insert(0, 255)
```

This is intended to iterate through each row adding a single element 255 to the start and end of each row. Unfortunately it adds 12 instances of 255 to both the start and end!

This makes no sense to me. Presumably I am missing something very trivial but I can't see what it might be. As far as I can tell it is related to the loop: if I write `stack[0].append(255)` outside of the loop it behaves normally.

The code is obviously part of a much larger script. The script runs multiple For loops, a couple of which are range(12) but which should have closed by the time this loop is called.

So - am I missing something trivial or is it more nefarious than that?

Edit: full code

step_size = 12, the code above is the part that inserts "right and left borders"

```
def classify(target_file, output_file):

import numpy
import cifar10_eval      # want to hijack functions from the evaluation script

target_folder = "Binaries/"   # finds target file in "Binaries"
destination_folder = "Binaries/Maps/"   # destination for output file

# open the meta file to retrieve x,y dimensions
file = open(target_folder + target_file + "_meta" + ".txt", "r")
new_x = int(file.readline())
new_y = int(file.readline())
orig_x = int(file.readline())
orig_y = int(file.readline())
segment_dimension = int(file.readline())
step_size = int(file.readline())
file.close()

# run cifar10_eval and create predictions vector (formatted as a list)
predictions = cifar10_eval.map_interface(new_x * new_y)

del predictions[(new_x * new_y):]     # get rid of excess predictions (that are an artefact of the fixed batch size)

print("# of predictions: " + str(len(predictions)))    

# check that we are mapping the whole picture! (evaluation functions don't necessarily use the full data set)
if len(predictions) != new_x * new_y:
    print("Error: number of predictions from cifar10_eval does not match metadata for this file")
    return

# copy predictions to a nested list to make extraction of x/y data easy
# also eliminates need to keep metadata - x/y dimensions are stored via the shape of the output vector
stack = []
for j in range(new_y):
    stack.append([])
    for i in range(new_x):
        stack[j].append(predictions[j*new_x + i])

predictions = None # clear the variable to free up memory

# iterate through map list and explode each category to cover more pixels
# assigns a step_size x step_size area to each classification input to achieve correspondance with original image
new_stack = []
for j in range(len(stack)):
    row = stack[j]
    new_row = []
    for i in range(len(row)):
        for a in range(step_size):
            new_row.append(row[i])
    for b in range(step_size):
        new_stack.append(new_row)
stack = new_stack
new_stack = None
new_row = None     # clear the variables to free up memory

# add a border to the image to indicate that some information has been lost
# border also ensures that map has 1-1 correspondance with original image which makes processing easier

# calculate border dimensions
top_and_left_thickness = int((segment_dimension - step_size) / 2)
right_thickness = int(top_and_left_thickness + (orig_x - (top_and_left_thickness * 2 + step_size * new_x)))
bottom_thickness = int(top_and_left_thickness + (orig_y - (top_and_left_thickness * 2 + step_size * new_y)))

print(top_and_left_thickness)
print(right_thickness)
print(bottom_thickness)

print(len(stack[0]))
# add the right then left borders
for j in range(len(stack)):
    for b in range(right_thickness):
    stack[j].append(255)
    for b in range(top_and_left_thickness):
    stack[j].insert(0, 255)
print(stack[0])
print(len(stack[0]))
# add the top and bottom borders
row = []
for i in range(len(stack[0])):
    row.append(255)          # create a blank row
for b in range(top_and_left_thickness):
    stack.insert(0, row)    # append the blank row to the top x many times
for b in range(bottom_thickness):
    stack.append(row)       # append the blank row to the bottom of the map

# we have our final output
# repackage this as a numpy array and save for later use

output = numpy.asarray(stack,numpy.uint8)
numpy.save(destination_folder + output_file + ".npy", output)

print("Category mapping complete, map saved as numpy pickle: " + output_file + ".npy")
```

Comment: This code seems to function fine. The issue is probably in an outer for loop that causes this code to run 12 times. Can you post more of the code that this is contained in?

Comment: can you post your code for the outer for loops? The code ou posted seems to work fine

Comment: `for j in range(len(stack))` I'd really like to see the original tutorial where this loop is being taught and do some ranting in the comments. `for sublist in stack: sublist.append(255)`. Really. If you really need the index, use `enumerate()`.

Comment: Updated. You are both correct - I tried commenting out the other loops and the problem went away so it must be the loops interacting in some way. I can't see why they would interact though?

Comment: @P.Hopkinson This "appends at the end" smells a lot like "index variable gets carried over from previous loop". Remember that the iteration var from a for loop exists past the for loop (one of the few things that I'd really like to turn off in Python) and it's easy to accidentally reference a variable you did not want to reference.

Comment: @dhke - I assembled the code myself which is probably why it is eccentric! (I'm new to python). I adjusted to your version of the code (it makes sense) but the problem persists.

Comment: Ah, and the other thing I can think about (but not really see in your code rigth away) is the usual: "`a.append(row), a.append(row), a[0].append(0), a[1].append(0)`, i.e. forgetting about reference assignment.